# How do I estimate the mean of groups as well as subgroups within a group?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, glmm

For example,

I have three groups A, B, and C. A has two subgroups, A1 and A2. B and C don't have subgroups. I have multiple observations for each individual in these groups. I want to estimate the mean for A, B, C, A1 and A2.

Do I have 5 groups (A, B, C, A1 and A2) to do this? This seems like a weird way to do this. Any suggestions?

`y ~ (1|person) + group`

More context:
A is the set of users who join a community. A1 is the subset who return to the community, A2 users leave the community. So I want to see if there is a difference between A1 and A2, as well as difference between A and B, B being the their behavior outside the community. Let's ignore C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have four groups (A1, A2, C and D) to do it at first. After fitting the model with 4 groups, you can test if A1 and A2 groups have the different means. If not, the A1 and A2 groups can be merged together and fit a new model with 3 groups (A, B, and C). If A1 and A2 have different means, it is meaningless to have an average effect of A1 and A2.

Comment: That is a good idea! The issue is I'm trying to see if there is a difference in mean between A1 and A2, while trying to quantify the difference between A and B as a whole. To give some context, A is the set of users who join a community. A1 is the subset who return to the community, A2 users leave the community. So I want to see if there is a difference between A1 and A2, as well as difference between A and B, B being the their behavior outside the community. Let's ignore C.

Comment: A1 + A2 = A? or some users in A are not belong to A1 and not belong to A2?

Comment: Yes, A1 + A2 = A, there are no other users

Comment: If A1 and A2 have no difference, then they have common mean, you can combine them and find A-B. If there is difference between A1 and A2, I think you need A1-B and A2-B. BTW, in title "estimate slope" should be "estimate mean".

Comment: Got it, that makes sense, I guess I want to do A-B irrespective of the difference between A1 and A2, to get a sort of "net" effect, A1 and A2 can have different number of users, all in one model. I changed the title a while back to average, but mean is probably better. I'll fix.

Comment: Then you need two models, one with 4 groups to test/estimate A1-A2, another with 3 groups for A-B. But keep group C in the model, because it is possible to decrease the variance estimate. mean =  average.

Comment: Ahh, got it! I didn't know you could add groups to models with the explicit intention to decrease the variance estimate, is that a common thing to do?

Comment: A lot of people do not recognize the benefit of keep as many subjects as possible when fit the model. The variance is estimated by residual, so keep more subjects ==> more number of residuals ==> lower variance. Of course, if the number of subjects in C is low, you can exclude them.

Comment: Makes sense, is there a reference I can cite for this? I worry that reviewers may question the need for adding the extraneous C group.

Comment: No reference. You can try. fit the models with and without C, comparing the p-value and width ot 95% confidence interval. It is not always true. If C has large variance within itself, then keeping C will be bad.